# How to send data from a C# application to a C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, ui, c#

I have a C++ graphics engine and I would like to build an editor for it in C#. I want to be able to send data from the editor to the engine such as what tool is being used and any user-defined parameters.

In a previous [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12791/hosting-opengl-c-window-in-c-wpf), I have already found a method to render my C++ engine to a C# window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C++ CLR (Common Language Runtime) Class Library simplifies the interop process between C++ and C#.

> Ensure that the project configurations (x86 or x64) match between the
> C# application and the C++ CLR Class Library to prevent compatibility
> issues.

**1. Create the C++ CLR Class Library:**

Start by creating a new C++ CLR Class Library project in Visual Studio. This type of project allows you to write managed C++ code that can be easily accessed from C#.

**2. Define the Managed Class:**

Start by creating a new C++ CLR Class Library project in Visual Studio. This type of project allows you to write managed C++ code that can be easily accessed from C#.

*MyCppCLRClass.h*

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace MyCppCLRClassLibrary
{
    public ref class MyCppCLRClass
    {
        public:
            void SendMessageFromCSharp(String^ message);
    };
}
```

*MyCppCLRClass.cpp*

```
// MyCppCLRClass.cpp
#include "MyCppCLRClass.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace MyCppCLRClassLibrary
{
    void MyCppCLRClass::SendMessageFromCSharp(String^ message)
    {
        std::cout << "Message received in C++ CLR Class: " << msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(message) << std::endl;
        // Process the message or perform any required actions
    }
}
```

**3. Build the C++ CLR Class Library:**

Build the C++ CLR Class Library project. Visual Studio should generate a managed DLL that you can use from your C# application.

**4. Create the C# WPF Application:**

Create a new C# WPF application project or use your existing one.

**5. Reference the C++ CLR Class Library:**

In your C# project, add a reference to the compiled C++ CLR Class Library DLL.

**6. Call the Managed C++ Functions:**

In your C# code, you can directly call the functions exposed by the managed C++ class:

```
using System;
using MyCppCLRClassLibrary;

namespace MyCSharpWpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "Hello from C#!";
            MyCppCLRClass myCppCLRInstance = new MyCppCLRClass();
            myCppCLRInstance.SendMessageFromCSharp(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**7. Run the Application:**

Run your C# WPF application, and when the button is clicked, it should call the function in the C++ CLR Class Library.